# State update fails even after reducer setSignupData runs successfully. signupData is still null. why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am updating the state of `signupData` but after update it is still showing `null`.

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  signupData: null,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: { 
    setSignupData(state, value) {
      console.log("payload:",value.payload)
      state.signupData = value.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setSignupData } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

```js
dispatch(setSignupData(userSignUpData));
console.log("user signup data", userSignUpData)
console.log("sign up data set to :", signupData)
```

As you can see, `payload` and user sign up data has valid values, but still sign up data is `null` after state update.

[signupData value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ7cG.png)

Comment: Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve]? You are likely console logging a stale enclosure over whatever `signupdata` is where you are trying to update it and log the value. If you really just want to log state updates use the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I am updating signupData during signup process in signup. js file then using current state of Signup Data to take some other actions in another file.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

This just looks to be an issue of a stale closure over the selected `signupData` state from the store in a function callback that is dispatching an action to update the state.

### Stale vs current state access demo

[image: Edit state-update-fails-even-after-reducer-setsignupdata-runs-successfully-signupdat]

## Suggested Solutions

You've a couple options for accessing the current state:

1. Use the `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the state to log the value or issue any other intentional side-effects.

   ```js
   const signupData = useSelector(/* selector function */);

   ...

   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("sign up data set to:", signupData);
   }, [signupData]);

   ...
   ```
2. Import the `store` object and call [`store.getState()`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) to access the current state.

   ```js
   import store from '../path/to/store';

   ...

   const someCallback = ( .... ) => {
     ...
     dispatch(setSignupData(userSignUpData)); // <-- dispatch action
     const state = store.getState();          // <-- get current state
     const signupData = state....signupData;

     console.log("user signup data", userSignUpData);
     console.log("sign up data set to:", signupData);
     ...
   };
   ```

If all you are *really* wanting to do is to check/validate/verify that state was updated as a result of dispatching an action, then you should ensure you've not disabled the [Redux-DevTools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools) and have the browser extension installed which allows you to inspect the store.

Comment: I found out the error. I am updating the state correctly. It is getting updated too in the reducer. But I m not importing it correctly in the other files.

Comment: I was using const { signupData } = useSelector( (state) => state. auth). I m not able to access the signupData from here.

Comment: @Akash Is there an additional issue with how you are using the `useSelector` hook? Have you been able to apply one of the suggested solutions from my answer to access/verify the state update?

Comment: I tried the first one but it was showing errors that we can not use useEffect hook becuase my page was not an react component or funcn.

Comment: const { signupData } = useSelector( (state) => state. auth)                                           or     const signupData =useSelector( (state) => state. auth.signupData) .                               I tried both but I could not access it in other files.

Comment: @Akash Oh boy, it's really unclear what you are even trying to do here. Sorry, I made the assumption you were trying to do something in a callback in a React component. Can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] so we've better and full context what you are trying to do in the code?